# Player multi urls

Tags: php, jquery, flash, jquery-plugins

I have an array with many urls. I want to play them all inside an mp3 player. Do you know a player like this:

http://www.alsacreations.fr/dewplayer-en

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JW Player can play a playlist of audio / video files: http://www.longtailvideo.com/players/jw-flv-player/

**EDIT**

JW Player is fully configurable, you can test options here http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player-setup-wizard/

If you specify a 24px height you'll have nothing more than the control bar. If you want to change the skin you can choose one from the official skins http://www.longtailvideo.com/addons/skins

Comment: Why don't use Deplayer anyway?

Comment: Not work i have tryed a file audio like this
[link](http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?q=Mathieu-Imbert&tl=en)